# Отработать положенное время и завершить работу

Tags: c#, winforms, таймер

Есть функционал, который работает в асинхронно в отдельном потоке. По истечению пусть 3 минут, надо прервать выполнение. Что то типа подобного псевдокода:

```
Timer1.start() //Запустить таймер
funct_work(); // Запускаем функционал
while (Timer1.value() < 3); // проверяем прошло ли 3 минуты, если нет продолжаем работу. 
Timer1.Stop(); // время работы вышло
```

Пока на данный момент получилось это:

```
funct_work();
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
timer.Interval = 1000;
timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick); // в функции timer_tick идет увеличение глобальной переменной
timer.Start();
if (glob_time < 180){;}else{timer.Stop()}
```

Однако проблема, что условие выполняется 1 раз. Если поставить цикл, то функция timer_tick() не выполняется.

Помогло вынести объявление System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(); глобально.
Вынести timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick); в main(ибо при каждом запуске функции навешивался еще один обработчик и таймер ускорялся)
Проверку glob_time вынес в функцию timer_Tick. После чего все заработало.

Comment: И? Что не получилось?

Comment: Не мой основной язык, потому могу предоставить только псевдокод, хотелось бы правильный синтаксис. + Насколько я понимаю объявление в основном потоке, ведет к его зависанию(пока цикл не закончиться).

Comment: Какого типа приложение: WinForms, WPF, другое? Добавьте тег.

Comment: Добавил тег, немного расписал, что получилось

Comment: Странный код или это куски какие-то, непонятные. Он даже вроде и работать как надо, не будет, ибо когда отработает условие `if (glob_time < 180){` - повторно оно уже не будет отрабатывать. Используйте планировщик задач.

Comment: В этом и проблема, что условие исполняется один раз. А цикл просто блокирует все.

Comment: На сколько я понимаю, тебе нужно разобраться с CancellationToken-ами и тасками. https://binary-studio.com/2015/10/23/task-cancellation-in-c-and-things-you-should-know-about-it/